# Spellchecking using recursive binary search

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have this recursive Binary Search Spellchecker method. sArray holds a list of words in the England dictionary. Key is any word you can send. The method will take any word(key) and look for it in the dictionary (sArray) using a recursive binary search.

I can't figure out how to properly navigate over the dictionary sArray for every word. Words such as "project" and "test" are found however words such as "the" and "by" aren't. I know this has to do with my recursion step however I have been unable to figure out the proper recursive step based upon the compareTo.

```
public int bSearch(ArrayList<String> sArray, String key, int lowIndex, int highIndex) {

    if (lowIndex > highIndex) {
        System.out.println("The word was not found ");


        return -1;
    }

    mid = (lowIndex + highIndex) / 2;

    if (sArray.get(mid).equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
        System.out.println("WORD FOUND");

        return mid;
    } else if (sArray.get(mid).compareTo(key) > 0) {

        return bSearch(sArray, key, lowIndex, mid - 1);

    } else {

        return bSearch(sArray, key, mid + 1, highIndex);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that 'the' is in `ArrayList`?

Comment: FYI, you can have a look at the built-in `Arrays.binarySearch()`.

Comment: The textbook bug is that the array needs to be sorted. Also you're using `equalsIgnoreCase()` but not `compareToIgnoreCase()` and need to be sorting 'ignored case'.

Comment: Without further information my first guess would be that your ArrayList isn't sorted properly. Could you provide a more detailed example?
Edit: Looks like Dan beat me to it.

Comment: The ArrayList is sorted alphabetically, do you think I am not adding/subtracting the mid during the recursive call?